# Python Vs C - Handling environment variable in Windows

Tags: python, c, environment-variables

I see a variation in output between C and python code in Windows trying to get the same functionality.  The c code ( similar to unix shell scripts ) shows the TEST1 environment variable in 'test.bat.output' with its value as empty string whereas the python code removes this environment variable.

Is there a way to ask Python not to remove the environment variable from environ table when it is empty?

### C

```
#include <windows.h>

main()
{

  DWORD dwRet;
  char pszOldVal[1024] = "abc";

  if(! SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST1", ""))  
    puts("Error\n");

  // _putenv("TEST1=");

  // GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST1", pszOldVal, dwRet);
  system("cmd /c test.bat >test.bat.output");
}
```

### Python

```
import os
os.environ['TEST1'] = ""
os.environ['TEST2'] = "karthik"
os.system("cmd /c test.bat > test.bat.output.python")
```

-Karthik

Comment: Please learn to use Stack Overflow code formatting.

Comment: Hmm. S.Lott, you stomped over my edits...the edit system is kind of borky like that. :( Anyway, yes. Code formatting is important.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the desired semantics of an environment variable with an empty value?

Comment: I will definitely following the code formatting rules. Thank Lott for pointing out.

Setting a variable to empty string in Windows is equivalent to 'unset' in Linux if I am not wrong. But this behavior should be atleast consistent in C and python under Windows.

Comment: I replied to your comment on my answer.  You might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible answer.  I don't have a Windows system handy to test with, so I don't really know what this code will do, but what happens if you do this:

```
import os, subprocess
myenv = {}
myenv.update(os.environ)
myenv['TEST1'] = ""
myenv['TEST2'] = "karthik"
subprocess.Popen(('cmd', '/c', 'test.bat'), stdout=file("test.bat.output.python", 'w'),
                 env=myenv).wait()
```

In my opinion, you might be encountering a Python bug of some kind.  Especially if the code I just gave works.

Also, testing your code under Unix does work.  The environment ends up with an empty environment variable in it.

Comment: Your suggestion to get the copy of environ and using it for subprocess works. Could the C code also work the same way internally?

Comment: My theory on why it works is that there is a difference between the way the API the os.environ variable uses and the API that subprocesses uses.  My guess is that the API that os.environ uses is geared towards old programs that expect setenv to delete an environment variable when it is set to empty.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-platform compatibility between Windows and "most everybody else" (operating systems derived or inspired from Unix) is often hard to get, especially in the innumerable corner cases that inevitably arise (e.g., as in this question, "does setting an environment variable to empty mean unsetting it"). Sometimes it's just easier to access Windows specific functionality directly rather than trying to stretch the "cross-platform" functionality.

While the traditional way to access Windows-specific functionality from Python is the [win32all](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html) extension package, in recent Python versions the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) standard library module offers an alternative with the advantage of requiring no installation of C coded extensions.  An interesting project is [jaraco.windows](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jaraco.windows/1.3), a set of pure-Python code on top of `ctypes` to make Windows operations easier and smoother.  For example, if you work with the environment and/or the registry, the [environ.py](https://svn.jaraco.com/jaraco/python/jaraco.windows/jaraco/windows/environ.py) module offers a nice set of functions and classes with a more Pythonic feel to them than the bare win32 API as accessed by the underlying `ctypes` (e.g., get an exception with a readable error message in it in case of errors, rather than having to check return codes &c).

Comment: Not surprisingly, there's now newer versions of [_jaraco.windows_](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jaraco.windows) available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes empty values are not being put into environ, but interesting thing is calling  SetEnvironmentVariable from win32api or ctypes module has same affect as os.environ though win32api.SetEnvironmentVariable would be calling the same function as in C .

So are you sure you get different result in C code?

```
import win32api
import os
win32api.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST1", "")
# or 
# import ctypes
# ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST1", "")
os.system("echo %TEST1%")
```

Comment: I could easily see `putenv` and `SetEnvironmentVariable` having completely different semantics under Windows.

Comment: but atleast invoking SetEnvironmentVariable from python has same effect as with os.environ or putenv

Comment: I don't have win32api or ctypes module to try immediately in my python installation. But what I said about the C code is true. Can you please check at your end?